# code wont print despite proper booleans

Tags: java, printing, numbers, boolean

I am writing a code for my Java Class where i have to find a 4 digit number. That consist of four different numbers, the thousands digit is 3 times the tens, the number is odd and all the digits add up to 27.

I did the math on paper and it should be 9837, but my java code does not print, can anyone help please?

```
public class Batman {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isFourDifferent = false;
    boolean isThousand3TimesTens = false;
    boolean isOdd = false;
    boolean is27 = false;

     for (int number = 0; number < 10000; number++) {
        int d0 = number % 10; number /=10;
        int d1 = number % 10; number /=10;
        int d2 = number % 10; number /=10;
        int d3 = number;

        if ((d0 != d1) && (d0 != d2) && (d0 !=d3) &&
            (d1 != d2) && (d1 != d3) && 
            (d2 != d3))
            isFourDifferent = true;

        if (d3 == (3 * d1))
            isThousand3TimesTens = true;

        if (d0 % 2 != 0)
            isOdd = true;

        if ((d0 + d1 + d2 + d3) == 27)
            is27 = true;

        if(isFourDifferent  && isThousand3TimesTens && isOdd && is27)
        System.out.println("Found" + number);


}


}
}
```

Comment: As a side note: The boolean variables `is...` should be initialized _inside_ the loop because each number must be analyzed again.

Comment: As a debug hint: Print the number and the four boolean variables in each loop run. Maybe you see which one gets calculated wrong. (I did not analyze or debug your code. That's a task for you!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

1. You are changing `number` during each loop so that by the end of the loop, no matter what `number` was, it is now single-digit.  Because of this, you have an infinite loop.  Use another variable, initialized to `number`, for your calculations of `d0`, `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`.
2. You aren't setting your booleans back to `false` with each loop.  Move the declarations/initializations to the top of the `for` loop.

With the above changes, the code looks like this:

```
for (int number = 0; number < 10000; number++) {
     boolean isFourDifferent = false;
     boolean isThousand3TimesTens = false;
     boolean isOdd = false;
     boolean is27 = false;

     int temp = number;
     int d0 = temp % 10; temp /=10;
     int d1 = temp % 10; temp /=10;
     int d2 = temp % 10; temp /=10;
     int d3 = temp;

     if ((d0 != d1) && (d0 != d2) && (d0 !=d3) &&
             (d1 != d2) && (d1 != d3) && 
             (d2 != d3))
         isFourDifferent = true;

     if (d3 == (3 * d1))
         isThousand3TimesTens = true;

     if (d0 % 2 != 0)
         isOdd = true;

     if ((d0 + d1 + d2 + d3) == 27)
         is27 = true;

     if(isFourDifferent  && isThousand3TimesTens && isOdd && is27)
         System.out.println("Found" + number);
 }
```

Output:

```
Found9837
```

Comment: i fixed the two errors that you have point out, but the code still does not print anything out, it leaves me with what a scanner would do, ie type something in, but nothing happens

Comment: Oops.  I had indicated what to fix with the `temp` variable, but I didn't actually use it.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: oh okay, I see what you did now and what i was doing wrong, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're actually dividing the `number /=10;` which is the variable of your for loop.

what you can instead do is:

```
int inti=number;
inti/=10;
int d3 = inti%10;
inti/=10;
int d1 = inti%10;
```